# JSON stringify with AngularJS on the fly transformation

Tags: json, angularjs, stringify

Why can I not use something like this?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testVal">
<pre>{{JSON.stringify(testVal,null,4)}}</pre>
```

If I remove the JSON.stringify() method my code works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `| json` :

```
{{ testVal | json }}
```

or add `JSON` to `$scope` :

```
$scope.JSON = JSON
```

then

```
<pre>{{ JSON.stringify(testVal) }}</pre>
```

works

**http://plnkr.co/edit/PPXK36BbTslkK5FjfP4x?p=preview**

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest way to do it!

Answer (score 3):

The double brackets syntax `{{something}}` tells angular to look in the `$scope` object for a match.

So `{{name}}` matches to `$scope.name` set in your controller.

You can use methods in here (and I would recommend it to keep your view files clean) and this will resolve your problem.

So in the controller:

```
$scope.stringify = function(value, replacer, space)
{
    return JSON.stringify(value,replacer,space);
}
```

... then in your view:

```
<pre>{{stringify(testVal,null,4)}}</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the function in the controller:

```
$scope.stringify = JSON.stringify;
```